# How to calibrate camera and use it in real time?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to calibrate two cameras. I want to calibrate each one individually. At this point, my script can calibrate both cameras successfully. But now I want to use those calibrated cameras in real time. the code that I am using is the one available in the [OpenCV documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dc/dbb/tutorial_py_calibration.html).
Below is the code. I'll just share this part because it's the one that it's not working as I want.

```
def calibrateCamera(self, chessboardRows=9, chessboardCols=6, imshow=False):

    self.chessboardRows = chessboardRows
    self.chessboardCols = chessboardCols
    self.imshow = imshow
    chessboardSize = (self.chessboardRows, self.chessboardCols)
    criteria = (cv.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)
    
    objp = np.zeros((self.chessboardCols*self.chessboardRows,3), np.float32)
    objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:self.chessboardRows,0:self.chessboardCols].T.reshape(-1,2)
    
    objpoints = [] 
    imgpoints = [] 

    for path, index in zip(self.paths, self.indices):
        images = glob.glob(path + "*.png")

        for img in images:
            frame = cv.imread(img)
            gray = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            ret, corners = cv.findChessboardCorners(gray, chessboardSize, None)

            if ret == True:
                objpoints.append(objp)
                corners2 = cv.cornerSubPix(gray,corners, (11,11), (-1,-1), criteria)
                imgpoints.append(corners2)
                cv.drawChessboardCorners(frame, chessboardSize, corners2, ret)
                if self.imshow == True:
                    cv.imshow(f"Calibrated images, Camera{index}", frame)
                    cv.waitKey(0)
            
            if ret == False:
                print("No pattern detected")
                break

        ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1], None, None)

        print(f"Camera{index} matrix\n", mtx)
        print(f"Camera{index} distortion coefficients\n", dist)

        h,  w = frame.shape[:2]
        newcameramtx, roi = cv.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(mtx, dist, (w,h), 1, (w,h))

        mapx, mapy = cv.initUndistortRectifyMap(mtx, dist, None, newcameramtx, (w,h), 5)
        dst = cv.remap(frame, mapx, mapy, cv.INTER_LINEAR)

        x, y, w, h = roi
        dst = dst[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        cv.imshow('calibresult.png', dst)
        
        k = cv.waitKey(0)
```

Can anyone help me to use this "remap" in real time?
And, lastly, is there any limitation in terms of frame rate to use this kind of method in real time?
Thanks in advance,

Comment: what's a "rempar"? -- welcome, helpful: [tour], [ask], [mre]

Comment: Ups. I didn't notice that error, sorry.

Comment: sorry about the question, but what do you mean by "untouched camera images"?

Comment: please do take the [tour]. this is important. -- "untouched" means before remap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Christoph, you should use `cv.initUndistortRectifyMap` only once, outside your loop, to generate the map. Then, at each frame, you can use `cv.remap`.

Remapping (or undistorting) the entire image comes at a cost (especially for large images). Working on distorted images and only undistorting some selected points might be a better options. The function you can use to do so is `cv.undistortPoints`.

More information is available in the documentation of OpenCV.

https://docs.opencv.org/4.6.0/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga55c716492470bfe86b0ee9bf3a1f0f7e

Answer (score 1):

From calibration (OpenCV's `calibrateCamera()`, not your own function), you gain "intrinsics", i.e. camera matrix and distortion coefficients.

Store those intrinsics.

Then call `initUndistortRectifyMap()` with those intrinsics. You receive lookup maps suitable for `remap()`. You do this once, not for every video frame.

Then you use `remap()` on video frames, using those maps.

`remap()` of an entire image is fast enough for real-time processing but it has some cost still.

If you can, do your processing on untouched camera images (those frames you have before you call `remap()`). Then undistort whatever *point* data you get from your processing. Undistorting points is also not cheap, but cheaper if done on a few points instead of an entire image.